# Scanning an image (bar code)

Tags: java

I'm trying to scan a bar code for black and white lines (across the image from left to right). Can anyone help me in doing this? There are 95 bits in my bar code image and I want to scan across just once and get the values of those colors scanned with the .getRed, .getGreen, .getBlue methods.

I'm not sure if I started out right, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
//Image already loaded in above code

//Scan Array
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++ {
}
}
```

I was told that the code above scans the whole entire image and not just once from left to right. Any help?

Edit:

- Black lines would give (0, 0, 0) which would then equal to 1.
- White lines would give (255, 255, 255) which would then equal to 0.

Comment: 95 bits, is this just one line? You don't need an y axis then. Also image/im seem to be 2 different objects

Comment: @user2875404, I want to scan down horizontally the middle of the image. So, I guess that's why I put the y-axis in.

Comment: can you pls upload a sample picture of the bar code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do this yourself. Use Zebra Crossing.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/

You'd need to scan across a row, find contrast, find threshold, create candidate lists of valid width predictions and what the bar code could be, and sort them... it is a enormous headache.

Comment: Everything is perfect. I have it set to the exact location of pixels where the white/black starts to where the white/black ends. Widths and Heights are good to go.